# How to split elements in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
list = ['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0', 'Name1, Location1', 'Phone number1']
```

I want to split it as below

```
list = ['Name0', 'Location0', 'Phone number0', 'Name1', 'Location1', 'Phone number1']
```

I tried code below but it doesn't work.

```
list = ['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0', 'Name1, Location1', 'Phone number1']
newlist =[]
newList = [line[0].split(',') for line in list]
print(newList)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Beside the point, but `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). Use a more descriptive name, or at least something like `lst`. For an example, see [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](/q/31087111/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small list you can try this:

```
lst = ['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0', 'Name1, Location1', 'Phone number1']
s = ", "
joined = s.join(lst)
newList = joined.split(s)
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
['Name0', 'Location0', 'Phone number0', 'Name1', 'Location1', 'Phone number1']
```

Comment: It's worked properly. Thanks you

Comment: You can accept it as answer if it works properly

Answer (score 3):

```py
lines = ['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0', 'Name1, Location1', 'Phone number1']
print([token for line in lines for token in line.split(', ')])
# Outputs ['Name0', 'Location0', 'Phone number0', 'Name1', 'Location1', 'Phone number1']
```

This is the same as the following nested for-loop:

```py
lines = ['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0', 'Name1, Location1', 'Phone number1']

result = []
for line in lines:
    for token in line.split(', '):
        result.append(token)

print(result)
```

Comment: It working well, Thanks you for help