# How to split string in list

Tags: python

Original list:

```
lines = [['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0'], ['Name1, Location1', 'Phone number1']]
```

I want to get new list as below:

```
newLines = [['Name0', 'Location0', 'Phone number0'], ['Name1', 'Location1', 'Phone number1']]
```

I tried code below but it is not work ([How to split elements in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68247717/how-to-split-elements-in-list/68247790?noredirect=1#comment120625352_68247790)):

```
for line in lines:
    for token in line.split(', '):
        result.append(token)
print(result)
```

How to make it work?

Comment: How are the original and new lists different? What does "not work" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know there are two nested list, so there should be two nested `for` loop to iterate the list. And you should use another `for` loop to iterate the `split()` result. The code may be like this:

```py
lines = [['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0'],
         ['Name1, Location1', 'Phone number1']]
result = []
for line in lines:
    result.append([])
    for fields in line:
        for token in fields.split(', '):
            result[-1].append(token)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['Name0', 'Location0', 'Phone number0'], ['Name1', 'Location1', 'Phone number1']]
```

Comment: To me, it is a big help. Thank

Comment: @ThetCartter My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate the strings in the sub-lists first before you can split each of the strings into tokens:

```
[[token for tokens in line for token in tokens.split(', ')] for line in lines]
```

This returns:

```
[['Name0', 'Location0', 'Phone number0'], ['Name1', 'Location1', 'Phone number1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to loop through the inner array as well, as it looks like you'll be getting an error for trying to split a list. As the split will be actioning on this line:

```
['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0']
```

So you need another loop to action on the strings like:

```
result = []
# loop the array 
for line in lines:
    # If you want to keep the inner arrays, reset each loop 
    current = []
    # Now loop the inner array
    for item in line:
        for token in item.split(', '):
            # Add the items to an array
            current.append(token)
    # Add these inner arrays to the larger array
    result.append(current)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
lines = [['Name0, Location0', 'Phone number0'], ['Name1, Location1', 'Phone number1']]


newLine = []


for line in lines:
    temp = []
    for element in line:
        temp.extend(element.split(', '))
    newLine.append(temp)
```